# How to change forecolor of Software Center descriptions?

Tags: software-center, fonts

Due to some change I did to the system which I cannot remember, the text in my Software Center is no longer visible (the description, version, etc of the software). It shows when I highlight on where the text should be. So apparently the forecolor of the text has changed to white which is same as the background color.
How can I change this?

Comment: Try changing your system theme and see if that helps.

Comment: I went to Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Colors and changed the forecolor of Windows and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: How do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: Write it as answer and then mark as answered.

Answer (score 3):

I went to Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Colors and changed the forecolor of Windows and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This link has plenty of tips and tricks for UBUNTU 10.04 LTS and 10.10 MAVERICK.

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/ubuntu-tips-and-tricks.htm#Change-Font-Panel-Clock

So let me know if it is of some help.

Regards,
Krishna Kumar